# OnComplete Event insert input value - jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, uploadify

I have a problem.

I'm using the jQuery plugin Uploadify v. 2.1.4 to upload some *.pdf files.

The Uploadify have the OnComplete event callback function. This event returns in your arguments the file name sended.

I created a input hidden with id #pdf_name, where i want when the oncomplete function executes, him pass the file name argument to the input hidden, changing your value.

I don't know how i can "insert" an value inside a input with the jQuery.

Anyone have a solution?

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/oncomplete-2/

Thanks,
Luiz H.

Comment: So where's your code?  You don't expect us to do all the work from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZfLG/

```
var fileName = name_argument;
$('#pdf_name').attr('value',fileName); //set value of the input field
```

Comment: @Sparky672 : that's awsome. I did not know about this. Thanks for sharing this info which is something new to me :)

Comment: In the case of `value`, it would not matter, but anything that is considered a property will not work with `attr()` as of jQuery 1.6.

Comment: Perfect, Lokesh. Is exactly what i need and its working. Very thanks, really. And i'm sorry about my english, heheh.

Answer (score 0):

This is really very basic jQuery:

```
$("#pdf_name").val(filename_argument);
```

if the "input id = "#pdf_name" includes the # sign you will either need to remove the "#" from the id (suggested) or add another "#" to the jQuery selector.